# Why is the subclass type not available when an instance property is initialized by a static member?

Tags: swift

When the following code is run, the `self` inside of `defaultModuleName` is `ReactViewController` when one would expect it to be `FooViewController`. Why?

```
class ReactViewController: UIViewController {

    var moduleName: String = defaultModuleName

    static var defaultModuleName: String {
        let t = String(reflecting: self) // Also tried NSStringFromClass
        guard let s = t.split(separator: ".").last else { return "" }
        guard let r = s.range(of: "ViewController") else { return "" }
        return String(s.prefix(upTo: r.lowerBound))
    }

}

class FooViewController: ReactViewController {

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad();
       print(moduleName); // Prints "React"
   }

}
```

Comment: It works as expected in my test. Can you post a minimal self-contained example, with expected and actual output?

Comment: It turns out that the important part is `var moduleName: String = defaultModuleName`. `defaultModuleName` returns the correct value in other contexts, but not here.

Comment: When I put a breakpoint on that line, the debugger tells me that the type I'm "in" is `BarViewController`, but when I step into `defaultModuleName`, the type becomes `ReactViewController`.

Comment: This feels like a bug to me, @Hamish.

Comment: I'm on a roll. This is the second interesting bug I've found in a short time: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-6452

Comment: @GregoryHigley I've posted an answer, will go ahead and delete my comments now.

Comment: It should be noted that @Hamish opened a bug for this at https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-6480

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty interesting; it appears that the `self` available in a property initialiser is merely the type that the property is defined in, rather than the dynamic type of the instance being constructed.

A more minimal example would be:

```
class C {
  static var foo: String { return "\(self)" }
  let bar = foo // the implicit 'self' in the call to 'foo' is always C.
}

class D : C {}

print(D().bar) // C
```

In the property initialiser for `bar`, the implicit `self` is `C.self`, not `D.self`; despite the fact that we're constructing a `D` instance. So that's what the call to `foo` sees as `self`.

This also prevents `class` member overrides from being called from property initialisers:

```
class C {
  class var foo: String { return "C" }
  let bar = foo 
}

class D : C {
  override class var foo: String { return "D" }
}

print(D().bar) // C
```

Therefore I regard this as a bug, and have [filed a report here](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-6480).

Until fixed, a simple solution is to use a *lazy* property instead, as now `self` is the actual instance (upon the property being accessed for the first time), which we get can get the dynamic type of with `type(of: self)`.

For example:

```
class C {
  static var foo: String { return "\(self)" }
  // private(set) as the property was a 'let' in the previous example.
  lazy private(set) var bar = type(of: self).foo
}

class D : C {}

print(D().bar) // D
```

Applied to your example:

```
class ReactViewController : UIViewController {

  lazy var moduleName = type(of: self).defaultModuleName

  static var defaultModuleName: String {
    let t = String(reflecting: self) // Also tried NSStringFromClass
    guard let s = t.split(separator: ".").last else { return "" }
    guard let r = s.range(of: "ViewController") else { return "" }
    return String(s.prefix(upTo: r.lowerBound))
  }
}

class FooViewController : ReactViewController {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print(moduleName) // Prints "Foo"
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the title of my question is misleading considering the answer. I'm thinking about reducing my question to its essence and changing the title. Any suggestions on the title?

Comment: @GregoryHigley Hmmm... how about something like "*Why is the subclass type not available when an instance property is initialized by a static member?*". Bit of a mouthful though.

Comment: Beggars can't be choosers. I'll go with it.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass `self` instead of `type(of: self)`, and use the `String(describing:)` initializer.

```
class ClassA {

    static var className: String {
        return String(describing: self)
    }

}

class ClassB: ClassA { }

print(ClassB.className) // prints "ClassB"
```

EDIT: clarification on the `var moduleName: String = defaultModuleName` update. Suppose I add this line to the above example (same idea):

```
class ClassA {

    // This is a property of ClassA -> it gets implicitly initialized
    // when ClassA does -> it uses ClassA.className for its value
    var instanceClassName = className

    static var className: String {
        return String(describing: self)
    }

}

class ClassB: ClassA { }

print(ClassB().instanceClassName) // prints "ClassA"
```

This new `instanceClassName` is not static, so it is an instance property on `ClassA`. It is therefore initialized when `ClassA` is initialized (*not* when ClassB is initialized). Ergo, a property being set within `ClassA`, using a reference to `className`, will print out `ClassA`.

Comment: Yes, this works, but my code is subtly different. Give it a try as written.

Comment: The only additional wrinkle I see in your code is that you remove the "ViewController" substring, which is just a string operation irrelevant to the question at hand. Do you mean something else?

Comment: Yes, `var moduleName: String = defaultModuleName`. Try something like that and you'll get a different result. :)

Comment: Also, `type(of: self)` was a typo when I copied the code over from memory. It was never in the original code, so the problem does not lie there.

Comment: That `var moduleName: String = defaultModuleName` is doing exactly what it's supposed to. See my edit for an explanation.

Comment: Take a look at the comments on my original question and the minimal example @Hamish posted: http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/5a1c8c531a4354330faa09cb

Comment: Never mind, it _does_ work as you described, it's just that it is not supposed to, as it contradicts the behavior in your earlier example and is not polymorphic (as it should be).

Comment: @Hamish has filed a bug for this. Let's hope it gets fixed.